# 2 insert querys 2 tables inserts

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Using a simple form I am posting into database. However its only posting into the first table ($sql) and not the second ($sql2). But I can not work out why. All the names match the values ect...

Am I missing something stupid. Any assistance would be great. 
Here is the part where its inserting $sql but not $sql2

I appreciate that the question of inserting data into to tables has been asked. However its not worked for me and want to check if I am missing something silly or going about this the wrong way.

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO accounts ( reg, acc, accstatus, carrfloor, carramid) 
VALUES ( '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg'])}', 
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['acc'])}', 
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['accstatus'])}', 
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['floor'])}',   
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['carramid'])}' )"; 
   
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO platform ( platform, name, platformstatus, platformtype) 
VALUES ( '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['platform'])}', 
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}',
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['platformstatus'])}',    
         '{$db->real_escape_string($_POST['platformtype'])}' )";
   
$insert = $db->query($sql); 
$insert2 = $db->query($sql2); 


if ($insert && $insert2) { 
echo "<font color='red'>Inserted Successfully</font>"; 
//header('Location: index');
} else { 
echo "<font color='red'>Woops! Something Went Wrong :|</font>"; 
} 


$db->close(); 
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: Also marking this as a duplicated and stating its answered under a complely different question I don't understand "How to get mysqli error in different environments?(link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments) "

Comment: Just do what is said in the linked answer.

Comment: Hi

I looked and the link and allowed it to show errors on screen. Except it was not seeing any error. However I know there is a problem as A:
When it goes through the if statement and check if both $insert && $insert2 was inserted it throughs out the false condition of "Woops! Something Went Wrong". But inserting into the first table but not the secound.

Comment: Can't be. There is either a succesful insert or an error. NO exceptions.

Comment: That's the point though. Its not giving me a mysqli error only the error of my if statement.  Also to check that it was to echo an error on screen since I added error_reporting(E_ALL);  and ini_set('display_errors',1); i purposely entered something wrong  and it then displayed an error as expected. Sorry of i'm being stupid.

Comment: So theirs nothing I can do? Its basically inserting first $sql into database, ignoring the $sql2. When it gets to the If Condition to see if both $sql and $sql2  where inserted echo's out error as required and confirm Woops something when wrong. Which is correct as only $sql was inserted into database, I have done error_reporting and nothing is displayed. this is now where I'm at and stumped :(

Comment: did you add the mysqli_error() command?

Comment: yes and checked it was working be purposely making a mistake in the query which then gave me an error.